# Trying to pass struct object to class haeder file

Tags: c++, class, oop, header-files

I'm trying to convert my project from only using one main file, to two file by putting all the struct and function to another header file. But it seem that I have conquered a problem when I compile. I don't know..I've editing here and there and right now.. it says that 'class ticket" has no member named 'b' in 'void ticket::loadData(ticket::destination*)' and 'void ticket::Booking(ticket::clientInfo, ticket::destination*)'. I'm still new in learning OOP and don't really know the concept. Is there anything that I left out or done wrongly?

```
//my ticket.h
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
class ticket
{
  private:


  public:
     struct clientInfo 
     {
            string name,
                       matric,
            phoneNum;

     };
     struct destination 
     {
            string destinasi;
                string city[2];
            string code[2];
            float price;

     };

    ticket(){}; 
    void loadData(destination b[13] );
    void MainMenu(clientInfo a);
    void Booking(clientInfo a, destination b[13]);
    void printOut(clientInfo a, destination b[13], int y, string);    
};

void ticket::loadData(destination b[13])
{
  tiket hi;
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open("negeri3.txt");

  if(!inFile) { cout << "Error Loading File!";}
  else  
  { 
      for (int x=0; x < 12 ; x++)
      {  
         getline(inFile, hi.b[x].destinasi, ',');
         inFile.ignore();
         //cout <<hi.b[x].destinasi<<"\t";   //seem like if i try to output this, there is an output

         if(x<8)
         {
           for(int y=0; y<2; y++)
           {
             getline(inFile, hi.b[x].city[y], ','); inFile.ignore();
             //cout <<hi.b[x].cityr[y]<<"\n";
           } 
           for(int l=0; l<2; l++)
           {
             getline(inFile, hi.b[x].code[l], ','); inFile.ignore();
           } 
           inFile>>hi.b[x].price; inFile.ignore();
         }
         else if(x>=8)
         {
           getline(inFile, hi.b[x].city[0], ','); inFile.ignore();
           for(int y=0; y<2; y++)
           {
             getline(inFile, b[x].code[y], ','); inFile.ignore();
           } 
           inFile>>hi.b[x].price; inFile.ignore();
         }
      } 
  }

 inFile.close();    
}

void ticket::MainMenu(clientInfo a)
{
 tiket k;
 //system("cls");

 cout << "\n\t\t====== TICKET BUS SYSTEM ======";
 cout <<"\n\n\t\t  WELCOME TO TICKET BUS SYSTEM";
 cout << "\n\n\t\t     PLEASE KEY IN YOUR DETAILS\n";
 cout<<" \n\t\t===================================";
 cout << "\n\n\t\t  NAME       : "; getline(cin, a.name);
 cout << "\t\t  MATRIC NO. : ";     getline(cin, a.matric);
 cout << "\t\t  PHONE NO.  : ";     getline(cin, a.phoneNum);
 cout<<" \n\t\t===================================";
 cout << "\n\n";

 //cout <<k.b[0].destinasi;
 cout << a.name;
 cin.get();


}

void ticket:: Booking(clientInfo a, destination b[13])
{
    tiket hi;
system("cls");
int hii = 0; 
string ngriMana, date;

cout <<"\n\t\tWELCOME "<<a.name <<" to TICKET BUS SYSTEM \n";
 cout <<"\t\tWE PROVIDE BUS SERVICE TO :-\n\n";
 cout <<left<<setw(25)<<"\t\tDestination"<<setw(12)<<"Ticket Price\n";
 cout <<right<<setw(48)<<"(USD)\n";
 cout <<"\t\t-----------------------------------";

 for (int x=0; x<12; x++)
{
    cout <<"\n\n\t\t"<<left<<setw(25)<<hi.b[x].destinasi<<""<<right<<setw(5)<<hi.b[x].price;   //but there is no output coming out from this fucntion

    for(int p=0; p<2; p++)
    { 
     cout <<"\n\t\t "<<p+1<<". "<<left<<setw(24)<<hi.b[x].city[p];}
}
 cout <<"\n\t\t-----------------------------------\n"; 

cout <<"\n\n\t\tINSERT YOUR BOOKING INFORMATION :-\n";
cout << "\n\t\tDEPART DATE  (DD/MM/YY) :: " ;           cin>>date;  
cout << "\t\tDestination (eg: SA for Shah Alam)  :: ";  cin>>ngriMana;


 for (int y=0; y<12; y++)
 {
     if(ngriMana == b[y].code[0] || ngriMana == b[y].code[1] )
        {
         cin.get();
         cin.get();
         printOut(a,b,y,date);
         hii = 1;
         }

  }

 if ( hii== 0)
 {
     for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
     {
              if( ngriMana != b[i].code[0] || ngriMana != b[i].code[1])
      {
        cout <<"\n\n\t\tYou have entered a wrong destination code! Please Try again";
        cin.get();
        cin.get();
           Booking(a,b);
      }
    }
   }
}
```

and here is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include "tiket.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    tiket ha;
    tiket::clientInfo a;
    tiket::destination b[13];

ha.loadData(b);
ha.MainMenu(a);
ha.Booking(a,b);

system("cls");
cout <<"\n\n\t\tTHANK YOU FOR USING OUR BUS SYSTEM :)\n";
cout <<"\t\tPLEASE REFER AND PRINT YOUR RESIT\n\t\t";
cout<<"\n\n\t\t";
system("PAUSE");
return 0;

}
```

and my negeri.txt contains

```
Johor (JOH), Batu Pahat, Mersing, JOH, joh, 30
Kedah (KDH), Sg Petani, Alor Star, KDH, kdh, 65
Kelantan (KEL), Kota Bharu, Tanah Merah, KEL, kel, 60
Kuala Lumpur (KL), Bandar Tasik Selatan, Pudu, KL, kl, 38
Melaka (MEL), Melaka Sentra, Masjid Tanah, MEL, mel, 28
Negeri Sembilan (NS), Seremban, Port Dikson, NS, ns, 30
Pahang (PAH), Kuala Lipis, Kuantan, PAH, pah, 40
Penang (PNG), Butter worth, Sg Nibong, PNG, png, 60
Perak (PRK), Ipoh, PRK, prk, 50
Perlis (PER), Kuala Perlis, PER, per, 70
Selangor (SA), Shah Alam, SA, sa, 32
Terengganu (TRG), Kuala Terengganu, TRG, trg, 50
```

Comment: Don't you get compiler errors as you mixed up naming tiket and ticket in your code?

Comment: well actually in my original code i use tiket as my class n I change it a bit when I want to post it in here as ticket.. my bad because I did not manage to change all of them

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should fix the typos in your code (`tiket` - `ticket`). Then you should create a `ticket.cpp` file and move your function implementations there. When you put implementations of non-inline functions inside a header file you will get multiple definition errors when including it from more than one cpp file.

You should also avoid writing to `cout` and getting user input within the `ticket` member functions. Try to separate user interaction from data storage.

Comment: well actually in my original code i use tiket as my class n I change it a bit when I want to post it in here as ticket.. my bad because I did not manage to change all of them